# Cannot access custom view with findViewById

Tags: java, android

I've written a small wrapper around ExoPlayer to abstract away some of the implementation details and add in some of our own business logic. The signature for this wrapper looks like so:

```
public class BFPlayer extends PlayerView {
```

Now I have an activity using this view and I wish to programmatically access the view so I can call methods on it. Here's my current code:

```
public class PlayBroadcastActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_broadcast);

        BFPlayer player = findViewById(R.id.player);

        player.displayMessage("Test");
    }
}
```

And the XML for this activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PlayBroadcastActivity">

    <com.blueframetech.bfplayer.BFPlayer
        android:id="@+id/player"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is throwing the error:

```
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
/Users/stevenbarnett/Source/BluePlayer/AndroidSDK/app/src/main/java/com/blueframetech/blueframesdk/PlayBroadcastActivity.java:16: error: cannot access PlayerView
        BFPlayer player = findViewById(R.id.player);
                          ^
  class file for com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView not found
1 error
```

Why is this happening? The error references `com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView`, but I'm attempting to access a ***subclass*** of `PlayerView`. Why is it trying to access this third-party dependent library? Also, why is the attempt failing?

Comment: "Why is it trying to access this third-party dependent library?" -- for inheritance purposes, I imagine. "why is the attempt failing?" -- is `BFPlayer` in the same module as `PlayBroadcastActivity`, or are they in separate modules?

Comment: @CommonsWare `BFPlayer` is in a separate module. The goal is to release `BFPlayer` as a JAR that can be included into third-party applications (this way our customers can make custom apps that play our content with our business logic and ad sources). And so there's an Android Library module for `BFPlayer` and an app module for testing it.

Comment: In the module that contains `BFPlayer`, for the ExoPlayer dependencies in `dependencies`, are you using `api`, `implementation`, or something else?

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm currently using `implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.9.5'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Java/Kotlin code to use a class, the compiler needs access to all classes in the inheritance hierarchy, so it has access to the full range of `public` members. Since `BFPlayer` extends `PlayerView`, consumers of `BFPlayer` need access to `PlayerView`.

However, in your module that contains `BFPlayer`, you have ExoPlayer integrated using `implementation`. This says "use this dependency for this module, but do not mark it as a transitive dependency for any other modules that depend on this module". For an app module, `implementation` is fine, as there are no other modules that depend on an app module.

However, `BFPlayer` is in a library module. So, `implementation` prevents modules that depend upon the `BFPlayer` module from having access to ExoPlayer.

99.44% of the time, in a library module, you want your main dependencies to be using `api`, not `implementation`, so consumers of the library module also pull in those other (transitive) dependencies.

So, change `implementation` to `api` in the `BFPlayer` module for the ExoPlayer dependency (and any others, presumably), and you should be able to get past your problem.